# Scrollbar not working in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made a WPF application. I have added a scrollbar to it, but whenever I minimize or maximize the window it's not working accordingly. I dont want to use coding. Please tell me how to make the scrollbar work according to window by setting properties only. I have used a grid also. Please help.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what isn't working about it? can you show us what you have done?

Comment: Do you have also other controls (like StackPanel) on it ?  
Could you show us your .xaml ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple way of using a scrollbar is to place a [`ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750665.aspx) in your window and put then elements within this `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer>

  <Grid>
     ....
  </Grid>

</ScrollViewer>
```